# Pandas sum all columns of group result into a single result

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've generated the following dummy data, where the number of rows per id range from 1 to 5:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import random
import functools
import operator
uid = functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, [np.repeat(x,random.randint(1,5)).tolist() for x in range(10)], [])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list("ABCD"), data= np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(len(uid), 4)))
df['id'] = uid
df.head()
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D  id
0  1  1  2  2   0
1  1  2  4  4   0
2  2  3  3  2   0
3  4  3  3  1   1
4  1  3  4  4   1
```

I would like to group by id then sum all the values, I.E:

```
   A  B  C  D  id
0  1  1  2  2   0
1  1  2  4  4   0
2  2  3  3  2   0 = (1+1+2+2+1+2+4+4+2+2+3+3+2) = 29
```

Then duplicate the value for the group so the result would be:

```
   A  B  C  D  id  val
0  1  1  2  2   0  29
1  1  2  4  4   0  29
2  2  3  3  2   0  29
```

I've tried to call sum `df.groupby('id').sum()` but it sums each column separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sum all columns without `id` and then using [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['val'] = df.drop('id',1).sum(axis=1).groupby(df['id']).transform('sum')
```

Another idea:

```
df['val'] = df['id'].map( df.groupby('id').sum().sum(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set_index` and then `stack` folowed by `groupby` and `sum`, then `series.map`

```
df['val'] = df['id'].map(df.set_index("id").stack().groupby(level=0).sum())
```

Or as suggested by @jezrael, sum has a level=0 arg which does the same as above:

```
df['val'] =  df['id'].map(df.set_index("id").stack().sum(level=0))
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D  id  val
0  4  2  4  1   0   34
1  3  4  4  2   0   34
2  2  4  3  1   0   34
3  1  1  1  3   1    6
4  2  3  1  4   2   50
```

Comment: @jezrael `sum(level=0)` is a wrapper over `groupby(level=0).sum()` , cleaner though. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
M=df.groupby("id").sum()
np.sum(M,axis=1)
```

```
print(M)
print(np.sum(M,axis=1))
```

First M is the sum of all columns which grouped by id. Then after grouping by id, when we sum all data in a row basically we have wanted result